# Creating a development Environment SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, installation, virtual-machine, development-enviroment

I want to install SharePoint on my laptop for development purposes. I'll probably have Windows7/8 in the laptop when purchased.

The idea is to have a dual boot system, one for the original Windows7/8 and the other into a virtual machine. Then install SharePoint onto the virtual machine.

Previously I've used esxi but don't think this will work in the manner mentioned above. Will VMware workstation provide a solution ?

Comment: **UPDATE:**
From what I understand: You are suggesting when the laptop boots it loads into a VM environment Then from here I can choose which OS(s) to launch ? So I could launch just my window7/8 or the Servers ? The boot loader could be EasyBCD or VM Player ?
<br />
By choosing Virtual Box of Hyper-V wont this take up resources as these products sit on top of Window 7/8 The default OS?

Comment: Dual boot means you can have two or more operating systems. Here there won't be any resource congestion, i.e if you go with Virtual Machines (which require a host OS to start with), then the resources gets shared between the Host Win7 and the Server VM.

Comment: _'which require a host OS to start with'_ Can this be a lightweight VM where the user can choose which OS's to launch? Which product(s) can do this?

Comment: It depends on how much RAM your laptop has. As I said you can get a decent experience if you can allocate 8 GB to the Virtual Box running Windows2008+SharePoint

Comment: No You will boot to windows 7 and then start Virtual Box. You can treat it as a separate software.

Comment: I've just read that VMware Player is based on the same concept. It needs a host OS.

Comment: Will try out Virtual Box. I was really looking for a solution that doesnt require a host OS and boots directly into a VM environment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Virtual Box provided by Oracle.

Here are the high level steps you should execute

1. Create a new VM
2. Choose OS = Windows 2008 64 bit
3. Set memory (8GB Works pretty well)
4. Choose hard disk - Existing vhd file or create new one (here you need to install everything like OS, SQL, SharePoint etc)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ritazh/archive/2011/02/24/host-sharepoint-2010-vm-with-virtualbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

VMware workstation would work as proposed... I've also used the free VMware player for some coursework I've done with Windows Server 2008, Exchange and SQL Server -- so the free version should also do the trick if you have a windows host: http://www.vmware.com/products/player

For those using OS X I tend to like Parallels (which is not free), but they're all just as capable (including Virtual Box which is free) so it's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a virtualization system is not a good idea for me, SharePoint consumes a lot of resources. In order to take full advantage of your computer's capabilities, I recommend doing this :

- create a vhd (Virtual Hard Disk)
- add it to the boot loader with the [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) tool
- boot on the new machine and install your new environment on it

I highly not recommend to set up a dev environment on a public version of windows (7/8), I tried that and the platform wasn't stable enough.

Feel free to comment if you need more details.

Comment: Hi - I always though dual boot it optional choice its OS1 or OS2 etc ? so what will the base OS be ?

Comment: @OrangeJuice : If you choose to do it a la dual boot, the host OS will be your default OS, i.e. windows 7 or 8.

Comment: **UPDATE:**
From what I understand: You are suggesting when the laptop boots it loads into a VM environment Then from here I can choose which OS(s) to launch ? So I could launch just my window7/8 or the Servers ? The boot loader could be EasyBCD or VM Player ?

By choosing Virtual Box of Hyper-V wont this take up resources as thies products sit on top of Window 7/8 The default OS?

Comment: @OrangeJuice : Sorry but I've made a mistake and I fixed it. I as suggesting that using a virtualization system is not the best choice because the 2 operating systems will run in the same time and they will share the computer resources. With the dual boot option, you will create a vhd that you will add to your boot loader. When you reboot your machine, you will be prompted to choose one of the too machines, the first one is your default OS, the second one is your vhd. Choosing to boot on the vhd will give it the full computer resources and capabilities (full CPU, full RAM, ...).

Comment: Ok. But its probable that I require two machines (servers) to run toghether (SharePoint and AD) therefore I will require virtualisation. Also I wanted the laptop to behave like a normal machine so I can watch my DVD's :) This is why I suggested dual boot also. From what I understand now is that I dont need dual boot intead boot directly into EasyBCD or equivalent, this will launch mwy win8 and servers as required. ?

Comment: @OrangeJuice : EasyBCD is not a virtualization tool, it's just a tool that helps adding vhd's to the boot loader (you can do that with the command line as well). The dual boot option will allow you to use only one OS at a time, but the running OS will have full computer capabilities. I think that you can run your DVD's in Windows Server, so think about the dual boot option ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20526/discussion-between-kgahbiche-and-orange-juice).

Answer (score 0):

You could run SP 2010 for development on a Win 7 x64 machine too -
  Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx

This post describes building a SP 2010 dev machine using (free) Virtual Box - 
How to build a SharePoint 2010 development machine
http://smallcitydesign.com/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-2010-development-machine/